Bootloader is corrupted somehow in dual boot system of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 24.04. How to fix?
Somehow bootloader is corrupted from time to time.  Eg, windows update, boot from live usb stick and so on.  I have tried to boot with live ubuntu installation usb stick and update the grub and do grub-install.  But no luck.  My current workaround is to install a dummy ubuntu and let the installer update the grub for me.  It takes longer.  As far as the installer can do the update and make grub working again. Then what exactly I need to do the achieve the same result without a dummy installation? Thanks.

Is this a UEFI or legacy install? What exact command did you try with grub-install, and what errors did you see?  Have you checked the fat filesystem on your efi partition (assuming an UEFI install)? More information helps us make better informed suggestions.

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

I used to the following procedure to manually fix the issue without success.  Steps to Repair GRUB Manually:
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/run
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
sudo chroot /mnt
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/run
sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi  # Only if mounted
sudo umount /mnt

Your current workaround is to install a dummy Ubuntu, and let the installer update the grub bootloader for you. A more efficient way of doing something like this is to create a new empty EFI boot partition manually before you install Ubuntu.
Use the GParted partition editor in an Ubuntu live session to create a new EFI boot partition located at the start of the disk space on which you plan to install Ubuntu. The EFI System Partition (ESP) needs to be 500MB, formatted as FAT32, and the partition needs to have the boot and esp flags set. The Ubuntu installer might require you to select the Manual partitioning option at the Installation type screen in order to recognize the EFI System Partition.

Thanks for your recommendation.  However, I don't understand the rationale behind create a new EFI boot partition manually will help.

Think of it as doing the same thing that you're doing when you start with the dummy Ubuntu installation, only you don't need to install a dummy Ubuntu installation. All you really need to do is to create an empty 500MB FAT32 EFI boot partition before you install Ubuntu.

Let's explain the working setup of my dual boot system of Windows 10 and ubuntu 24.04 before the corruption of bootloader (Once the corruption occurs, it boots straight to Windows 10 without the boot menu for selecting which system to boot).
/dev/sda1   EFI partition
/dev/sda3   Windows 10 partition
/dev/sda4   ubuntu partition

Whenever the corruption of bootloader occurs, my current workaround is to install a dummy ubuntu to /dev/sdb1 and have the bootloader of the dummy ubuntu installed on /dev/sda (not /dev/sdb).  Then the dummy installer will fix the grub/bootloader.  Upon the next power on, boot menu will show options to boot to dummy ubuntu, Windows, ubuntu (i.e. original one).  At this point, all three can be boot individually and properly.  Then I'll boot to the original ubuntu and update-grub and grub-install.  After that, I'll delete the dummy ubuntu and have a working dual boot system as before corruption.

I need help on the proper steps to restore/update the bootloader instead of the inefficient way of doing a dummy installation.  Thanks.

OK, I give up on my previous suggestion for now and make a new suggestion instead. Try reading the answers to Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot. That question seems more in line with what you are trying to do.
